# Serve online learning models with mlflow

Tags: python-3.x, mlflow, mlops

It is not clear to me if one could use mlflow to serve a model that is evolving continuously based on its previous predictions.

I need to be able to query a model in order to make a prediction on a sample of data which is the basic use of mlflow serve. However I also want the model to be updated internaly now that it has seen new data.

Is it possible or does it need a FR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should be able to do that by implementing the custom python model or custom flavor, as it's described in the [documentation](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#model-customization).  In this case you need to create a class that is inherited from `mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel`, and implement the `predict` method, and inside that method you're free to do anything.  Here is just simple example from documentation:

```py
class AddN(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def predict(self, context, model_input):
        return model_input.apply(lambda column: column + self.n)
```

and this model is then could be saved & loaded again just as normal models:

```py
# Construct and save the model
model_path = "add_n_model"
add5_model = AddN(n=5)
mlflow.pyfunc.save_model(path=model_path, python_model=add5_model)

# Load the model in `python_function` format
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_path)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my intuition as well, however I would only be able to save the model once, because the save_model takes a PythonModel and loaded_model returns a PyfuncModel that cannot be saved again.

Comment: I didn't try it myself, but maybe look to https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#custom-flavors. Or add a method to your class that will return new PythonModel instance that could be saved? Or even write data directly from model

Comment: What I ended up doing was saving the model once and saving the model (pickle) as an artifact of that run. Then I would just get the run from the model register every time I need to run the model (and overwrite the model pickle).